# GetStringAsync fails when IIS Binding set to specific IP

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core

I have an issue with my app communicating with a website, but only when the bindings are set to use a Specific IP (i.e., 172.16.9.86).  If I leave the binding as '*' (All Unassigned) the app works correctly.

[image]

The app is making the call to the website using HttpClient (.NET Core 3.1) like so:

```
try
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync("https://myServer.myDomain.com/SecureKeyTest/rdTemplate/rdGetSecureKey.aspx?Username=admin");
                
    Debug.WriteLine(responseBody);
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
}
```

I can take that same URL and paste it into Chrome and it works to retrieve the SecureKey, even when the binding is still set to a specific IP address, so I don't understand how the `HttpClient` call is different from the call from Chrome.

I have scoured hundreds of posts I have found on this issue and almost all claim that adding the `SecurityProtocol` settings is supposed to fix this issue, but it hasn't. The certificate used for this website is a fully registered company certificate, not a self-generated one.

EDIT: forgot to add the exception message I get:

```
    The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
--- End of inner exception stack trace 
--- at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacketAsync(Stream transport, AsyncProtocolRequest request) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional() at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use the IP address instead of the host name with HttpClient? By the way, I hope you are not exposing admin functionality without authorization.

Comment: @Crowcoder Same result using the IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you don't have a corresponding IP based certificate mapping for that IP address in Windows HTTP API,

https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings

Comment: Is this program usable with full IIS (not IIS Express)?  When I open it the only options I see are all referring to IIS Express.

Comment: @BrianKE you can run netsh command at command prompt to analyze mappings, or run Jexus Manager as administrator if you want to check IIS settings.